# Suggested edit only changing the number of spaces used as indentation

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I was presented [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18863376) this morning.

I must say I don't really know what to do in this scenario :

The edit doesn't improve anything, it only changes the indentation from 2 spaces to 4.

Should I still approve it, or reject it as *no improvement whatsoever* ?

Comment: I'd vote for _"no improvement whatsoever"_, because the amount of indentation is just a matter of personal preference. IMHO, as long as it is correct and consistent, the amount of indentation should not be touched.

Comment: Already rejected.

Comment: _The edit doesn't improve anything_: the answer is in the question.

Comment: @TGrif Not really. In *my* eyes it didn't improve anything. The goal of this question was to see if there was an "etiquette" regarding the number of spaces used as indentation here, and if an edit only changing this was to be considered useless. Now I know :)